# Problem with action constraint. bones jump to random places and the animation breaks

Tags: animation, armature, bones, constraints, actions

I have animated multiple bones of this armature, but after applying theaction constraint to the bones, some bones are jumping to different location and rotation as their starting values, some bones are alright, but this ends up breaking the entire animation. I have the problem detailed in the blend file, I duplicated the armature. One has action constraint applied to it, and the other doesn't, the one without the action, is how the animation is supposed to be.

[image]

Comment: It's a little difficult to see exactly what's going on in your blend file, without any meshes attached to the armature, but one likely cause of any problems here for you is that you're using your animation twice.  Your action constraints are set to "before original", so they are combining with your existing action-- and, your armature is assigned the exact same action as the action used by the bone constraints.  So you're doubling your transforms.  Give the armature a new, empty action on the dope sheet/action editor.